# C++ event driven json stream reader

Tags: c++, json, streamreader

I just discovered YAJL project which just does what I need.

- Read from stream
- Callback on each valid parsed token
- Reparse incomplete json when new data arrived

But I prefer C++. Of course I can use this library from C++ project and even write my own wrapper if I really want to but anyway native C++ is preferable.

I looked at JsonCPP but looks like it can't read incomplete json data from stream.

Is there any other C++ libraries for parsing json streams?

Some more requirements:

- lightweight. boost or Qt are not suitable
- I need something what I may freely use in commercial closed source software (mit, public domain, etc).
- Support for not blocking read. or allow to feed data (append_incoming_data).

Comment: I am sure http://json.org had at least a few C++ implementations. Scroll down on the main page.

Comment: non of them are suitable. I'll correct my question with more requirements

Comment: There are 11 different implementations for C++ alone (excluding C). _Surely_ there's one there that will do what you need?

Comment: they all have some flaws: blocking and don't have feed method, expecting complete json, stupid implementation allowing to parse only subset of json. It's from first look. maybe I'm wrong for some

Comment: @Rion did you find what you want?

Comment: @user1034749, as far as I remember, no.

Comment: new arrivals to this thread may want to check [boost json stream reader](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__stream_parser.html).

Answer (score 3):

Recently I search library with similar requirements,
and actually found only 1.5 libraries that support such requirements:

1. https://github.com/kazuho/picojson

one header library, `BSD` licence, and have interface like this:

```
Iter parse(value& out, const Iter& first, const Iter& last, std::string* err);
```

so you can create  `append_incoming_data` with a couple of lines of code.

2. https://github.com/dropbox/json11
   one file library, licence similar to `BSD`, `c++11` support, but interface
   that allow parse partly arrived from network `json` it require patch:

https://github.com/dropbox/json11/pull/55

**P.S.**

> lightweight. boost or Qt are not suitable

Actually, they are not suitable because of

> allow to feed data

At now both `Qt5` `json` and `boost` `property_tree` can not parse
half ready `json`.

Answer (score 0):

Other options are

- [sjparser](https://github.com/dhurum/sjparser) - the parsing is based on schema specified
- [JsonReader](https://github.com/xquintana/JsonReader) - plain event based parser